# Clear Cart with Wordpress E-commerce plugin

Tags: e-commerce

I added a Merchant to the Wordpress E-commerce plugin. 
I want on the submit, after doing my curl() call, to clear the cart 
How do I do that?

([link to plugin page](http://getshopped.org))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to their docs: `$wpsc_cart->empty_cart();`